# How to add the joomla style tootltip error message to a form

Tags: error-handling, bootstrap, registration

I know, that joomla 3.x uses bootstrap, both css and js. When I am filling in the registration form and my password is too short for example, I start getting those javascript tooltip error messages. 
I have added an ajax call to the registration where I check the availability of the username and email. I am getting my string message back succesfully  with jQuery ajax. 
But How can I add that message to my username input field to be shown at the other tooltips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it!!!
You have to include:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

and the javascript is something like this:

```
jQuery("#user_name").attr('title','Kérem előbb válassza ki a hatályba lépés dátumát!');
jQuery("#user_name").tooltip('show');
```

Make sure that these two line are in the done method of your jquery ajax call.

Then you have to destroy it:

```
jQuery("#user_name").click(function(){
        jQuery("#user_name").tooltip('destroy');
});
```